# Ansible Playbook using variable stdout as input to create files

Tags: ansible, scripting, redhat, ansible-facts

I'm creating a playbook to verify all NFS present in fstab are mounted and also they are RW [read/write].

Here is the first block of my playbook that is actually working.
Compares the `mount` output with the current `fstab`.

```
  tasks:

    -
      name: Get mounted devices
      shell: /usr/bin/mount | /usr/bin/sed -n {'/nfs / {/#/d;p}'} | /bin/awk '{print $3}'
      register: current_mount
    -
      set_fact:
        block_devices: "{{ current_mount.stdout_lines }}"

    -
      shell: /usr/bin/sed -n '/nfs/ {/#/d;p}' /root/testtab | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}'
      register: fstab
    -
      set_fact:
        fstab_devices: "{{ fstab.stdout_lines }}"
    -
      name: Device not mounted
      fail:
        msg: "ONE OR MORE NFS ARE NOT MOUNTED, PLEASE VERIFY"
      when: block_devices != fstab_devices
```

Now to verify these are Read/Write ready:

1. I need to actually create a file inside the paths stored on `{{ current_mount }}`

1.1) If it succeed we move forward and delete the newly created files

1.2) If there is failure when creating one or all the files, we need to fail the playbook and `msg` which of them is not read/write [that mean, if we can't touch[create] a file inside then the FS then is not RW ]

I tried to do the below, but it seems that it does not work like that.

```
    -
      file:
        path: "{{ current_mount }}"/ansibletestfile
        state: touch
    -
      file:
        path: "{{ current_mount }}"/ansibletestfile
        state: absent
```

This is a sample of whats inside the `{{ current_mount }}`

```
/testnfs
/testnfs2
/testnfs3
```

After doing some research, it seems that to create more than one file within different FS listed in a variable I would have to use the item module, but I had no luck

Please let me know if there is a way to perform this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve:

1. create a file inside the paths stored on `{{ current_mount }}`

You need to [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) over `current_mount.stdout_lines` or `block_devices`, like:

```yaml
- file:
    path: "{{ item }}/ansibletestfile"
    state: "touch"
  loop: "{{ current_mount.stdout_lines }}"
```

For 1.1 and 1.2, we can use [blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html). So, overall, the code can look like:

```yaml
- block:
    # Try to touch file
    - file:
        path: "{{ item }}/ansibletestfile"
        state: "touch"
      loop: "{{ current_mount.stdout_lines }}"
  rescue:
    # If file couldn't be touched
    - fail:
        msg: "Could not create/touch file"
  always:
    # Remove the file regardless
    - file:
        path: "{{ item }}/ansibletestfile"
        state: "absent"
      loop: "{{ current_mount.stdout_lines }}"
```